# SQL Query to display final task status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table where I need to display final output of a process . A process will have 2 records with different id. If both are 'PASS' then only final result for process should display Success as 1 else Failed : 1.

```
ID,TASKID,STATUS
1 ,101   ,PASS
2 ,101   ,FAIL
```

So in this case overall status of process should display -> Success : 0 Failed : 1

```
ID,TASKID,STATUS
1 ,101   ,PASS
2 ,101   ,PASS
```

So in this case overall status of process should display -> Success : 1 Failed : 0.

Tried below query but did not succeed:

```
select 
TASKID  ,
case when taskstatus='SUCCESS' then 1 end)) as Success,
case when taskstatus!='SUCCESS' then 1 end)) as Failed
from XYZ 
where TASKID = '123'
group by TASKID
```

Comment: It is rather confusing that your code has `'SUCCESS'` but none of your sample data does.

Comment: Thats' just alias which I used . Success , Failed in query . We can use anything though

Answer (score 0):

You are not far off. You can count the successes and failures and then display them according to your logic.

For example:

```
select
  TASKID,
  case when failed = 0 then 1 else 0 end as success,
  case when failed = 0 then 0 else 1 end as failed
from (
  select
    TASKID,
    sum(case when taskstatus = 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end) as succeeded
    sum(case when taskstatus <> 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end) as failed
  from XYZ
  where TASKID = 123
  group by TASKID
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      TASKID,
      sum(case when STATUS='PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as Success,
      sum(case when STATUS='FAIL' then 1 else 0 end)  as Failed
from XYZ
where TASKID = '123';
```

Comment: No, with above approach it would display , Success : 1, Failed : 1 whereas we need to expect Success : 0, Failed : 1.

Comment: No, it works fine if you add the ```group by TASKID``` maybe it won't work but try this one it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      TASKID,
      MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS='PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Success,
      MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS<>'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Failed
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE TaskID = 101
GROUP BY TaskID
```